# How to prove this inequality on given set?

Tags: inequality, integers, convexity-inequality

Let $p,q\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and $pq\ne1$. Then prove that $$\frac{p+q-2}{pq}\le 1-\frac{1}{n}.$$ Moreover equality holds iff $(p,q)=(1,n)$ or $(n,1).$

**My attempt:** $$\frac{p+q-2}{pq}=\frac{1}{p}(1-\frac{1}{q})+\frac{1}{q}(1-\frac{1}{p})$$ which is less than or equal to $\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{q})+\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{p}).$ **Here if we choose $p$ or $q$ to be $1$ then $(1-\frac{1}{p})$ or $(1-\frac{1}{q})$ will be zero, so we take them to be $2$.**
And now to maximize further I choose $p$ and $q$ equal to $n$.

I am not sure about this bold line.

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: Can you see my attempt please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible approach is to fix $p$ and maximize the expression as a function of $q$:

If $p=1$ then
$$
 \frac{p+q-2}{pq} = 1 - \frac{1}{q} \le 1 - \frac 1n
$$
with equality iff $q=n$. Otherwise $p \ge 2$ and
$$
\frac{p+q-2}{pq} = \frac 1p \left( 1 + \frac{p-2}{q}\right)
\le \frac 1p \left( 1+\frac{p-2}{1}\right) = 1 - \frac 1p \le 1 - \frac 1n
$$
with equality iff

- $q=1$ and $p=n$, or
- $p=n=2$ and arbitrary $q \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}$.

Comment: Let $n=2$. Then equality holds for $(1,n), (n,1), (n,n)$. So this proof is wrong somewhere but where?

Comment: @rationalize: You are right, there was an error in the case $p \ge 2$: Equality holds in $\frac 1p \left( 1 + \frac{p-2}{q}\right)
\le \frac 1p \left( 1+\frac{p-2}{1}\right)$ if $q=1$ **or** $p = 2$ (with arbitrary $q$).

Comment: I got it but in first ineqality we are saying p=2 and then in next we are saying p=n. I got the feeling but how to write it explicitly.

Comment: @rationalize: You can for example distinguish the cases $p=2$ and $p > 2$.

Answer (score 2):

For $n=1$ it's obvious.

Let $n\geq2$.

Now, we see that we need to prove that $f(p,q)\geq0$, where
$$f(p,q)=(n-1)pq-n(p+q)+2n.$$ But $f$ is a linear function of $p$ and it's a linear function of $q$ and we know that the linear function gets a minimal value for an extreme value of the variables, which says, that it's enough to prove our inequality for $\{p,q\}\subset\{1,n\}$.

Can you end it now?

Comment: But $f$ involves the term $pq$, then how is it a linear function?

Comment: @rationalize  $f$ is a linear function of $p$, where $q$ is a constant. Agree?